# Is there a guaranteed order of operations within a systemd service?

Tags: systemd

Is there a precedence or order of operations for the performance of items in a [systemd service unit configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) file?

For example, [`ExecStartPre`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) operations obviously happen before [`ExecStart`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=). And multiple `ExecStartPre` operations are [each executed to completion, serially and in order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348457/11985).  Also, [`ExecCondition`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecCondition=) operations are defined to happen before `ExecStartPre` (and with a very specific ordering/execution).

And the [`RuntimeDirectory`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectory=) operation/creation happens before `ExecStart`.

But does the `RuntimeDirectory` operation/creation necessarily happen after `ExecStartPre` completion? (my experiments suggest that it does, but I might have been fooled may be a race condition -- or have experienced an implementation-dependent behavior).  Presumably `RuntimeDirectory` creation is also thus well after `ExecCondition` operations?

Similarly, do [`ExecStopPost`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=) operations necessarily happen before or after the `RuntimeDirectory` is removed?

Are there other subtle-but-implicit guaranteed orderings within a given service? Or, conversely, are there other operations that can happen in parallel (or otherwise have their ordering undefined)?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I can see this maybe being in-order, or could vary across distros

Comment: Note that the idea of "implementation-dependent behaviour" does not really exist here.   There _is no_ standard, and there _are not_ multiple implementations attempting to conform to a standard.  There is only one software, and there is no specification distinct from its user doco describing whatever it does in its latest version.

Comment: @JdeBP I was using the term loosely (and perhaps subconsciously, as a gentle poke about the lack of a rigorous spec) -- as `Joe` points out, "the latest version" can vary across distros (hence, "implementation-dependent").